# Research ideas on Homological Algebra

Tags: homological-algebra

I am planning on doing some personal studies and some poster research for some future conferences in Homological Algebra, does there exist a current list of outstanding problems in the field of Homological Algebra?

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a list of problems in homological algebra (also for the cohomology of groups and algebras). For a list by Brown see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151016170311/http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/%7Emas010/pdffiles/PROBAMTX.PDF).

One of the open questions is the *Toral Rank Conjecture (TRC)* for nilpotent Lie algebras. For a bit of context, recall the TRC
by S. Halperin in 1987 from topology:

**Toral Rank Conjecture (TRC)**. Let $T_r\rightarrow E\rightarrow B$ be a fibre bundle, where $T_r=S^1\times \cdots \times S^1$ is the $r$-dimensional torus and $B$
is a compact and simply connected space. Then the dimension of the cohomology of the total space $E$ satisfies
$$
\dim H^*(E)\ge 2^r.
$$
The version for complex nilpotent Lie algebras is as follows:

**Conjecture (TRC for nilpotent Lie algebras)**: The sum of the Betti numbers of a nilpotent Lie algebra $L$ satisfies
$$
\dim H^*(L)\ge 2^{\dim Z},
$$
where $Z$ denotes the center of $L$.